# In xcode, UIStackView height not changed

Tags: xcode, autolayout, uistackview

I put multiple UIView in UIStackView.
But, When I set the UIView's height under 50, the UIView's height is changed automatically to 50!!
I don't set any constraints into UIViews and UIStackview.
How can I solve this problem?
[stackview screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIN7Q.jpg)

[fixed height image screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVvqM.jpg)

Comment: Can you show us the constraints ?

Comment: I upload 2 screenshots. please show them. @Antzi